# Error loading /boot.js

Tags: angular

I'm trying to drop some authentication into my Angular2 app using this bit of code that was mentioned in the Angular2 gitter channel: https://github.com/ronzeidman/ng2-ui-auth and I think I may not be understanding something completely.

I get the following errors in the console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in (program):1

and

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in angular2-polyfills.js:138

But in the body of that second error, it says the following:

```
Evaluating http://localhost:3001/node_modules/ng2-ui-auth/src/auth
Error loading http://localhost:3001/app/boot.js
```

Relevant code:

app/boot.ts:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {AuthHttp} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Config, SATELLIZER_PROVIDERS, Auth} from 'ng2-ui-auth';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    SATELLIZER_PROVIDERS({providers: {google: {clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}}}),
    provide(AuthHttp, {
        useFactory: (auth: Auth, config: Config) => {
            return new AuthHttp({
                tokenName: config.tokenName,
                tokenGetter: () => auth.getToken(),
            });
        },
        deps: [Auth, Config],
    }),
]);
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>App Name</title>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script>System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));</script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <cw-api-app>Loading...<cw-api-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

config.js:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },
  map: {
    'angular2-jwt': 'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
    'browser': 'node_modules/angular2/platform/browser.js',
    'ng2-ui-auth': 'node_modules/ng2-ui-auth/export.js',
    'auth': 'node_modules/ng2-ui-auth/export.js'
  }
});
```

app/app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {UserService} from './services/user.service';
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component';
import {UserDashboardComponent} from './user-dashboard.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'cw-api-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div><p>Test!</p></div>
    <ul><li (click)="userFetch(event)">Blah</li></ul>
    <div class="user-info">
      <cw-user-dashboard [user]="user"></cw-user-dashboard>
    </div>
      <app-login></app-login>
  `
  directives: [UserDashboardComponent, LoginComponent],
  providers: [UserService]
})

export class AppComponent {
  public title = "App Name";
  public user: Object;

  constructor(private _userService: UserService) { }

  userFetch() {
    console.log("wtf");
    this._userService.getUserDashboard().subscribe(res => this.user = res);
  }
}
```

app/login.component.ts:

```
import {Component, AfterContentInit, ElementRef, Renderer} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
import {Auth} from 'ng2-ui-auth';
//import {NgMessages} from '../formComponents/ngMessages';
//import {CustomValidators} from '../formComponents/customValidators';
//import {DefaultHandlers} from '../httpDefaults';

/**
 * Created by Ron on 18/12/2015.
 */

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
//    templateUrl: '../templates/login_form.html',
    directives: [NgMessages, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})
export class Login implements AfterContentInit {
    form: ControlGroup;
    user = { email: '', password: '' };
    userControlsConfig = {
        email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, CustomValidators.email])],
        password: ['', Validators.required],
    };
    login() {
        this.auth.login(this.user)
            .subscribe(
                () => this.goToMain(),
                this.handlers.error
            );
    }
    authenticate(provider: string) {
        this.auth.authenticate(provider)
            .subscribe(
                () => this.goToMain(),
                this.handlers.error
            );
    }
    goToMain() {
        this.router.navigate(['Main']);
    }
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.element, 'app', true);
        if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            this.goToMain();
        }
    }
    constructor(private auth: Auth,
                private fb: FormBuilder,
                private router: Router,
                private element: ElementRef,
                private renderer: Renderer,
                private handlers: DefaultHandlers) {
        this.form = fb.group(this.userControlsConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using version 1.1.0 all files are merged there, you can map ng2-ui-auth to node_modules/dist/ng2-ui-auth.js or node_modules/dist/ng2-ui-auth.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at this: `Evaluating http://localhost:3001/node_modules/ng2-ui-auth/src/auth`, it tries to get the ng2-ui-auth/src/auth without the .js extention, in your config file you've put 

`packages: {
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },`
 
which means the default extension only exists within the 'app' folder, try adding default extension to the entire system or specifically to ng2-ui-auth. If you wish add this issue to my github and I'll just add all js extensions explicitly. 
 --- edit --- 
 Tried adding js extenstions, doesn't work well with typescript. concating everything to a single file may work but typescript supports only 'amd' and 'system' module types and people really like the commonjs one. If someone has a good solution for this he is welcome to make a pull request (it will probably be a gulpfile which handles it) 
 --- second edit --- 
 In version 1.1.0 all files are merged so this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

**UPD 1**: Finally I managed to resolve the initial problem: Implicit OAuth2 with Angular 2. Again, this is not a direct answer to topic starter, but might be more general answer.

Look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/homoluden/06ba0ba9f06212c49ecd)

There you will find how to implement Client Side OAuth2 with another Angular 2 TS code.

Credits to [Michael Oryl](https://github.com/michaeloryl/angular2-bootstrap4-oauth2-webpack).

======= Below is the Initial Answer ======

I don't have precise answer 'how do I fix it', but I believe the cause of the issue is related to the 'import' statements.

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';                      // << This works OK
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {NG2_UI_AUTH_PROVIDERS, JwtHttp} from 'ng2-ui-auth'; // << This tries to load a script from URL like '{SERVER_ROOT}/ng2-ui-auth', but gets the HTML from node.js
```

In 'node_modules' there is file 'angular2/core.ts' and the same path in second import statement. But 'ng2-ui-auth' has only 'export.ts'. I tried to change import path to 'ng2-ui-auth/export' without success.

It is possible that export.ts is supposed to be imported by default using the 'ng2-ui-auth' path so import statements exposed by Ron is correct. So, this is just my guess what I described above.

If I'm, right we need to find out what file should be used in 'import' statement.